# Where is the custom keyboard dictionary (spellcheck) located on iOS?

Tags: ios, spell-checking

I would like to know the location on disk where the learned words are stored for the spellchecker and how to reset them.

In addition it would be nice to know where are the spellcheck dictionaries located.

Comment: I already found answers for most questions, less the location of the bundled dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found on a forum that the location should be:

`/private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/dynamic-text.dat` - for English
`/private/var/mobile/Library/Keyboard/xx_XX-dynamic-text.dat` - for other languages, where xx_XX is the ISO language code.

To remove these dictionaries you can go to `Settings> General> Reset > Reset Keyboard Settings`.

[image]

## Hyphenation

`/System/Library/LinguisticData/...`

## Unigrams

`/System/Library/TextInput/...`

Comment: You likely already know this, but an Apple-published app cannot access these and be approved; all of that system-level stuff is outside the sandbox and results in automatic app denial. If you're doing it for the jailbreak market, as part of an enterprise program, or just for your personal use then you're fine, of course.

Comment: (Also, check your own answer as being correct so that people searching in the future will know that the correct answer can be found here. It's completely appropriate in Stack Overflow land to answer and accept your own question.)

Comment: @Matthew, You have to wait two days to be able to accept your own answer.

Comment: Ah, I'd forgotten that. Just in case. :)